# using checkpoint to predict, but each time get different result

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

> I am a newer to tensorflow. I have trained a CNN model , and get
>   checkpoint files.
>
> Then,I freeze the checkpoint files to "pb" proto. Referenced the website:https://blog.metaflow.fr/tensorflow-how-to-freeze-a-model-and-serve-it-with-a-python-api-d4f3596b3adc#.nxb8t2ylh
>
> Next,I load graph from pb file,and predict with it .But, the result is different at each predict(for example:the same picture may got 1,1.04,1.2,1.3 these scores)  , why? Did I miss save some variables?

Comment: Did you disable dropout regularization when predicting?

Comment: I didn't disable dropout~ but the network is fixed in checkpoint, how can I disable it when freeze the graph?

Comment: I don't know whether you can modify a frozen graph, but I don't think it's possible. I would recommend you to fix the graph first, and then freeze it again.